# How do i concatenate a variable and another array variable element in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

```
#bin/bash
p=11.123.25.36:1301
filecontent=(`cat "result" `)
for s in "${filecontent[@]}"
q="$p/$s"
do
echo $q
done
```

my expected o/p it should be displayed like

```
11.123.25.36:1301/aaa
11.123.25.36:1301/zzz
11.123.25.36:1301/xyz
11.123.25.36:1301/789
```

But I got the following error in my script.

> syntax error near unexpected token q=$p/$s

Comment: When you do `cat "result"` is just a string. Where is the file?

Comment: See [Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), do it as `while IFS= read -r line; do     printf '%s\n' "${p}/${line}"; done < "${result}"`

Comment: you need to give "do" statement right after the "for" statement . Move q="$p/$q" to below the "do" statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
p=11.123.25.36:1301 
filecontent=($(cat result)) 
for s in "${filecontent[@]}" 
do
q="$p/$s" 
echo $q 
done
```

better solution with `while` (@Inian version):

```
while IFS= read -r line; 
do 
    printf '%s\n' "${p}/${line}"; 
done < "${result}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have this `q="$p/$s"` outside the loop. Just put it inside:

```
for s in "${filecontent[@]}"
do
q="$p/$s"
echo $q
done
```